# is higher version iOS sdk include lower version iOS sdk's api?

Tags: iphone

I have set my projects base sdk to iPhoneOS 6.1. Is higher version iOS sdk include all api's which was in lower version iOS sdk 5.0 or iOS sdk 4.2?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, make sure to set the "minimum supported OS" version for your target, and you will likely see warnings if the API's you're using are marked as deprecated in the newer SDK's.

Answer (score 0):

Most APIs are included. However some APIs many be modified, deprecated, or even removed.

You should take a look at the API Diffs as it contains a full list of changes.

- [iOS 6.0 to iOS 6.1 API Diffs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS61APIDiffs/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012875)
- [iOS 5.1 to iOS 6.0 API Diffs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS60APIDiffs/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011959)
- [iOS 5.0 to iOS 5.1 API Diffs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS51APIDiffs/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011328)
- [iOS 4.3 to iOS 5.0 API Diffs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS50APIDiff/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011042)
- [iOS 4.2 to iOS 4.3 API Diffs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS43APIDiffs/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010594)

You can find a list of API Differences document at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/index.html (search for "API Diffs")